# Inventory bad visual issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

I'm making an inventory system for my mobile game. When I click the play button, I load my inventory with items in it, and when I pick up an item it happens to me :

[image]

Unity add item slot when I fist open my inventory and a new one when I pick up an item...
but if I first pick up item then open my inventory I haven't this problem.

> DisplayInventory.cs

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class DisplayInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InventoryObject inventory;

    public float X_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEM;
    public float Y_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEM;
    public float X_START;
    public float Y_START;
    public int NUMBER_OF_COLUMN;

    Dictionary<InventorySlot, GameObject> itemsDisplayed = new Dictionary<InventorySlot, GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        CreateDisplay();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    public void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Container.Count; i++)
        {
            if (itemsDisplayed.ContainsKey(inventory.Container[i]))
            {
                itemsDisplayed[inventory.Container[i]].GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].amount.ToString("n0");
            }
            else
            {
                var obj = Instantiate(inventory.Container[i].item.prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, transform);
                obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = GetPosition(i);
                obj.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].amount.ToString("n0");
                itemsDisplayed.Add(inventory.Container[i], obj);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreateDisplay()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Container.Count; i++)
        {
            var obj = Instantiate(inventory.Container[i].item.prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            obj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = GetPosition(i);
            obj.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = inventory.Container[i].amount.ToString("n0");
        }
    }

    public Vector3 GetPosition(int i)
    {
        return new Vector3(X_START + (X_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEM * (i % NUMBER_OF_COLUMN)), Y_START + ((-Y_SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEM * (i / NUMBER_OF_COLUMN))), 0f);
    }
}
```

> Player.cs

```html
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    public OpenCloseInventory openCloseInventory;
    public InventoryObject inventory;

    private void Awake()
    {
        openCloseInventory.inventory.SetActive(true);
        inventory.Load();
        openCloseInventory.inventory.SetActive(false);
    }
 
    ...

}
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found ! Rather than adding a slot, just check if there is already one and just modify the number of items.